# ASP Textbox MultiLine Text Counter

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Can anyone simplify my code please, this work on my page, but when I checked on Google Developer tool console, I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Below code:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCounter" runat="server" Width="250px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 <SPAN id="chars"></SPAN>  


<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var char2 = ($(this).find('textarea[id$=txtCounter]').val().length);
         if (char2 == 0) {
         $('#chars').text("100 Maximum characters"); }
         else { 
          $('#chars').text( char2 + " Characters Remaining"); }
           textchar();
          });

        function textchar() {
        $('textarea[id$=txtCounter]').on('keyup keydown change', 
        function (){
        var limit = 100;
        var lengthtxt = $(this).val().length;
        if (lengthtxt >= limit)
          { this.value = this.value.substring(0, limit); lengthtxt = limit; } 
        $('#chars').text((limit - lengthtxt) + " Characters Remaining")
        });
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: Could someone with direct tag editing privileges fix the tagging on this? It's clearly **not** [tag:asp-classic].

Answer (score 0):

You problem is with this line:

```
$('textarea[id$=txtCounter]').on('keyup keydown change',
```

txtCounter is not the client ID of your textarea control when rendered to the client. View your page source to find the client ID, or use:

```
$('textarea[id$=<%= txtCounter.ClientID %>]').on('keyup keydown change',
```

Here's my working example using a simple textarea:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <script src="./jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<textarea ID="txtCounter" Width="250px"></textarea>
<SPAN id="chars"></SPAN>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var char2 = ($(this).find('textarea[id$=txtCounter]').val().length);
    if (char2 == 0) {
       $('#chars').text("100 Maximum characters"); 
    }
    else { 
       $('#chars').text( char2 + " Characters Remaining");
    }
     textchar();
  });

  function textchar() {
    $('textarea[id$=txtCounter]').bind('keyup keydown change', function (){
       var limit = 100;
       var lengthtxt = $(this).val().length;
       if (lengthtxt >= limit){
           this.value = this.value.substring(0, limit); 
           lengthtxt = limit; 
       } 
       $('#chars').text((limit - lengthtxt) + " Characters Remaining");
    });
   }
</script>        
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes this also work.. thou I still got the same 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. :(

Comment: It should be easy enough to determine the client ID of your control from the page source. I'll add my working example to the answer with a simple html textarea. I'm also using an older jquery (1.6.4) and so i've swapped your "on" with a "bind" - you may have better luck with that...however, your problem is most likely with your selector, so find the ID and adjust the selector to grab it accordingly.